# bquote in mtext for two variables

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a histogram of some data, add a title and the mean and 
standard deviation of the data. I use `mtext` and `bquote`:

```
a <- rnorm(100)
hist(a, main="A")
mtext(bquote(mu==.(round(mean(a)), sigma==.(sd(a)))))
```

However, only mu is plotted and it seems I don't entirely understand `bquote`. How could I plot mu and sigma next to or on top of each other?

Comment: What don't you just use `mtext` and something like (untested) `paste('mu==',round(mean(a)),'sigma==',round(sd(a)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a combination of `bquote()` and  some `plotmath symbols`.

```
a <- rnorm(100)
hist(a, main="A")
mean.a <- round(mean(a))
sd.a <- round(sd(a))
mtext(bquote(mu== ~.(mean.a) ~ sigma== ~.(sd.a)))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want yo put on top of each other, since `plotmath` does not support newlines, you can create your lines one by one like this:

```
Lines <- list(bquote(mu== ~.(mean.a)),
              bquote(sigma== ~.(sd.a)))
mtext(do.call(expression, Lines),side=3,line=0.5:-0.5)
```

[image]