# Bquote and quote in R... how do I find out more?

Tags: r

On this forum, there are lots of posts about bquote and quote in R, such as:

[bquote: How to include an expression saved as a string object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130448/bquote-how-to-include-an-expression-saved-as-a-string-object)

and

[bquote in mtext for two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406824/bquote-in-mtext-for-two-variables)

My question: is there a "cheat sheet" or a manual, or any documentation which **lists all of the commands you can use in bquote**. For example:

- use [] for subscript
- use hat to get ^
  etc...

I have looked for ages but I cannot find such a list.

EDIT:
one of my favourite features about the command bquote, for me personally, is that you can take an R variable, say k <- 4, and convert this into a label for an axis using .(k)

I learned this through "trial and error" and by going through a lot of forum posts. Is there a tutorial / documentation which explains stuff like this?

Comment: Three words for learning:  Trial and error

Comment: Hi Richard. This is precisely what I've been doing. I've picked up a good handful of commands, but I would have thought there would be a good reference to find out others. I tried to use help() but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for `help("plotmath")`.

Comment: @Roland -- thank you so much. I have spent hours looking for this!

Comment: @Roland Please make this an answer.

Comment: Note that this hasn’t really got anything to do with either `quote` or `bquote`. It’s simply how R’s text plotting functions interpret arguments what are unparsed expressions rather than strings. `quote`/`bquote` simply provide a means of creating unparsed expression, and they’re not the only ways of attaining this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for expressions in text-drawing functions is documented in `help("plotmath")`. I agree that it is kind of hard to find. I found out (long ago) from an SO answer.

As @KonradRudolph correctly points out, this is not directly related to `bquote` and `quote`.